# Mapping an array to sort it in descending order on Matplotlib chart?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to build a bar chart with the bars shown in a descending order.

In my code, the numpy array is a result of using SelectKmeans() to select the best features in a machine learning problem depending on their variance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

flist = ['int_rate', 'installment', 'log_annual_inc','dti', 'fico', 'days_with_cr_line', 'revol_bal', 'revol_util', 'inq_last_6mths','pub_rec']

fimportance = np.array([250.14120228,23.95686725,10.71979245,13.38566487,219.41737141,
  8.19261323,27.69341779,64.96469182,218.77495366,22.7037686 ]) # this is the numpy.ndarray after running SelectKBest()

print(fimportance) # this gives me 'int_rate', 'fico', 'revol_util', 'inq_last_6mths'  as 4 most #important features as their variance values are mapped to flist, e.g. 250 relates to'int_rate' and 218 relates to 'inq_last_6mths'.
[250.14120228  23.95686725  10.71979245  13.38566487 219.41737141
  8.19261323  27.69341779  64.96469182 218.77495366  22.7037686 ]
```

So I want to show these values on my bar chart in descending order, with int_rate on top.

```
fimportance_sorted = np.sort(fimportance)  
fimportance_sorted

array([250.14120228, 219.41737141, 218.77495366,  64.96469182,
        27.69341779,  23.95686725,  22.7037686 ,  13.38566487,
        10.71979245,   8.19261323])

#  this bar chart is not right because here the values and indices are messed up.
plt.barh(flist, fimportance_sorted)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Next I have tried this.

```
plt.barh([x for x in range(len(fimportance))], fimportance)
```

[image]

I understand I need to map these indices to the flist values somehow and then sort them. Maybe by creating an array and then mapping my list labels instead of its index. here  I am stuck.

```
for i,v in enumerate(fimportance):
    arr = np.array([i,v])

.....
```

Thank you for your help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the values and indices are messed up

That's because you sorted `fimportance` (`fimportance_sorted = np.sort(fimportance)`), but the order of labels in `flist` remained unchanged, so now labels don't correspond to the values in `fimportance_sorted`.

You can use `numpy.argsort` to get the *indices* that would put `fimportance` into sorted order and then index both `flist` and `fimportance` with these indices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> flist = ['int_rate', 'installment', 'log_annual_inc','dti', 'fico', 'days_with_cr_line', 'revol_bal', 'revol_util', 'inq_last_6mths','pub_rec']
>>> fimportance = np.array([250.14120228,23.95686725,10.71979245,13.38566487,219.41737141,
...   8.19261323,27.69341779,64.96469182,218.77495366,22.7037686 ])
>>> idx = np.argsort(fimportance)
>>> idx
array([5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 0])
>>> flist[idx]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
>>> np.array(flist)[idx]
array(['days_with_cr_line', 'log_annual_inc', 'dti', 'pub_rec',
       'installment', 'revol_bal', 'revol_util', 'inq_last_6mths', 'fico',
       'int_rate'], dtype='<U17')
>>> fimportance[idx]
array([  8.19261323,  10.71979245,  13.38566487,  22.7037686 ,
        23.95686725,  27.69341779,  64.96469182, 218.77495366,
       219.41737141, 250.14120228])
```

`idx` is the *order* in which you need to put elements of `fimportance` to sort it. The order of `flist` must match the order of `fimportance`, so index both with `idx`.

As a result, elements of `np.array(flist)[idx]` correspond to elements of `fimportance[idx]`.

Comment: thank you. it works : ) I  cant accept your answer yet as too soon, will do later.